# Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps 42.1001.0 SupportMapFragment java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, google-play-services

I recently updated my Xamarin.Android app to Google Play Services v42.1001.0. Without any other code changes, I noticed that when creating a SupportMapFragment, the output throws the following errors:

> Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
>   Lcom/google/android/chimera/Fragment;

Further down the Stack-trace I see this:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.google.android.chimera.Fragment" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000006/DynamiteModulesB_GmsCore_prodmnc_alldpi_release.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000006/n/armeabi-v7a,
>   /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000006/n/armeabi,
>   /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]

As soon as I comment out the SupportMapFragment code, I no longer see this error.

I have:

- Made sure I have the latest SDK and Build tools installed
- Cleaned/Rebuilt the solution
- Verified that my manifest file targets the proper API versions that are supported by the new Google Play Services libraries as per the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/releases)

It seems to only be happening with the SupportMapFragment. It's also worth noting that my application does use the Multi-Dex build setting.

What else should I try?

Comment: Can you please use `ClassyShark.jar` https://github.com/google/android-classyshark and inspect your multiple `classes{x}.dex` files to see where `com.google.android.chimera.Fragment` lives? You may need to override the `multidex.keep` with this class so it makes the main dex list: http://www.jon-douglas.com/2016/09/23/xamarin-android-multidex-keep/